# Ioncube - obfuscation error

Tags: encryption, obfuscation, encode, ioncube

Currently I am evaluating ioncube for products developed by our company. 
When running the encoded product I'm getting

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class '[obfuscated]'
```

If I have anything like `DomDocument` in my code I get this error. I feel like if I have any php package installed and used Ioncube throws a error. I contacted Ioncube support and  I'm unable to get a solution.

Does anybody know how to use Ioncube with a code contain `DomDocument`, `imagick` like package usages?

Comment: Surely your problem comes from "DomDocument" getting obfuscated when you don't want that.    What do IonCube's docs say about preventing obfuscation of special names?

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscation renames latent symbolic information in the compiled code of ionCube files, using names that are nonsense, or in the case of functions, names that would not even be valid were they used in PHP source. The corollary of this is that any non-encoded context will fail that attempts to use a symbol that has been obfuscated, as expected.

To bridge between the encoded and non-encoded world, an obfuscation exclusion list can be specified to name the symbols that should not be obfuscated. Due to the nature of PHP, in code such as $a->foo(), it is in general unknown what class $a is an instance of, and therefore if excluding foo() from being obfuscated, foo() used in any class context (i.e. all foo()s) would need not to be obfuscated. This isn't really a problem as symbol renaming is much less important than new features such as code encryption with dynamic algorithmic keys, but it is still preferable not to blindly exclude from obfuscation every method that happens to share the same name as a method from a module, which is why methods of module classes are not excluded by default.

The upshot of this is that you should prepare an exclusion file of just the methods that you want to exclude. It would be useful to have pre-prepared lists of functions for all known modules, and this is likely to be available in a future release, but it is easy to produce this oneself either manually or automatically.

Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.